# Why can't I set this bool property to YES?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, boolean, xcode4.6

I have this model class, where I set a BOOL property in the setter of another property. But, as you can see in the screenshots, I cannot set it. Despite sending YES to the property, the setter gets a NO. This also happens, if I send a YES from another class and not just from within 'self'. The class itself is instantiated, so 'self' is not nil. I also checked, that the setter is always called from the main thread. And it also makes no difference, if I use an instance variable instead of a property.
The BOOL property is defined as

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL downloaded;
```

Here are the screenshots:

[image: Trying to set BOOl property pic 1]

[image: Trying to set BOOl property pic 2]

All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Because you hit the breakpoint before the assignment and the default value is NO?

Comment: What happens when you remove you custom setter and just use the one LLVM creates when you build?

Comment: You cannot trust the debugger variables view. Check with `p downloaded` in the debugger console or with NSLog() in your code.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: That would explain why the *instance variable* `_downloaded` is NO, but not why the *method parameter* `downloaded` is NO.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: Of course the instance variable _downloaded is not yet set. I know that! As Martin R stated, what about the parameter of the setter that is NO?

Why was the question downvoted? Did I miss anything obvious?

Comment: @rckoenes: Same thing. I added the custom setter just to check if the YES is actually assigned.

Comment: @MartinR: The console says it's 'NO' and also says the if clause that checks this property.

Comment: I copied your code, and it worked correctly for me. I assume you checked that you're getting into the "if" statement rather than the "else" statement. Could there be somewhere in your code that's resetting _filePath to nil or @"", that causes that setter to be called again?

Comment: Hm, how about that! I just renamed the project folder in order to create a new blank project. Guess what, it worked with the renamed folder! And it still works after I renamed the folder to its original name.